# Why does ffmpeg.exe started from Windows batch file close immediately without waiting for user input?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

I searched google for an hour but I could not find anything to fix my issue. I found only "similar" fixes for problems I'm not having.

I am opening `ffmpeg.exe` from a batch file that only has `ffmpeg.exe` with no arguments in it and it doesn't work even though it did few hours ago.

If I open command line from the folder and enter `ffmpeg.exe` it works because it's not closing `ffmpeg` but waits for my input which is exactly how the batch file worked before.

What could be the issue?

I have not changed the batch file or `ffmpeg` one or their locations.

Running on Windows 7 x64 if that matters.

**Edit:** File name is `start ffmpeg.bat`. It's content is only `ffmpeg.exe` which used to work. I also tried `start ffmpeg.exe` and `ffmpeg` and changed the filename to `1.bat` and `1.cmd` but neither worked.

**Edit2:** Sorry i can't explain myself better my english isn't very good, however I will try to explain using these images:

[image: This is what i get if i run CMD and write ffmpeg.exe]
This is what i get if i run CMD from the desktop and enter ffmpeg.exe

[image: This is what I get when i run the batch file (after i added pause)]
This is what I get when i run the batch file (after i added pause)
Batch contents: 1st line=ffmpeg.exe, 2nd line=pause.

As you can see without the pause ffmpeg will terminate and not remain on the screen like the in first image.

I tried renaming the file and I tried to run it as admin but neither worked, Any suggestion why is it suddenly not running as it did yesterday?

Comment: In cases such as this, not providing us with the batch file content and name will greatly reduce your chances of getting help. Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: Open the command prompt and run the script from there instead of double-clicking the script. At least this way you'll be able to see what error is being thrown.

Comment: Please see my 2nd edit and if you require info I didn't provide please tell me.

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two images beyond the presence of a `pause` in the second image. Both terminate with the usage text displayed.

Comment: @user2566350 Why do you use a batch file just for starting `ffmpeg` at all? Create a shortcut (`*.lnk`) file with `"%ProgramFiles%\Path to ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe"` as command line and a suitable *Start In* directory (or let it empty) and use that shortcut. I think (not verified) with that shortcut stored in __Send To__ folder and no *Start In* defined, right clicking in a folder and left clicking in submenu *Send To* on the shortcut item opens a command process with `ffmpeg.exe` running in that directory.

Comment: @SomethingDark the difference is that i can still use the first window while the 2nd doesn't let me (it just exits),  Gerhard Barnard gave me a solution below by using a cmd /k which does what i wanted, to keep the window open from batch.

Comment: @Mofi I use that in a program to automate a video conversation but it just stopped working and the problem was that the window would close prematurely, cmd /k did the trick and now it's working again, thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So first things first. I suppose you meant your batch file name is `ffmpeg.bat` and not `start ffmpeg.bat` but you are calling it from cmd.exe as `start ffmpeg.bat`?

Regardless, never call your batch file names the same as the executable name.

Then why do you need to run start? You can just call the executable inside the batch file with full path. When doing start it will initiate a new cmd window which is not needed. So this should work just fine.

```
"C:\program files\wherever ffmpeg is\ffmpeg.exe"
```

In a batch file it will automatically wait for the external program to close before it will exit the batch. if you are unsure as to why it closes, it probably gave an error. You specifically said it *"does not work, even though it worked a few hours ago"*. That is not conclusive. so then just add a pause at the bottom of your script to catch the exeption.

```
"C:\program files\wherever ffmpeg is\ffmpeg.exe"
pause
```

**EDIT**
After you added screenshots, ffmpeg is still running fine. That is the idea of a batch file is to run and exit when done. ffmpeg.exe obviously completed as it showed you the command is not complete, and will exit. This does not happen when you run from cmd as you have a session in keep mode. So if you want to start the session and wait, then just make your batch like this:

```
cmd /k ffmpeg.exe
```

Comment: Start is just something i added when it stopped working, didn't help either.   Also i did add pause and there is no error in ffmpeg, Please note that if i simply run ffmpeg from the command line IT WORKS but not from a bat/cmd file that it's only argument is calling the app name (nothing else) and that is my issue for some reason running this silly 1 word bat doesnt start ffmpeg but calling it from command line does, this is where i require help!

Comment: did you try full path like i said?

Comment: ok saw the edit. that ia normal. ffmpeg exited because no arguments were passed. try `cmd /k ffmpeg.exe` in batch.

Comment: Ok that stopped the CMD from closing and unlike the pause i can still type but i must reference ffmpeg again but this is only a minor setback i could easily adapt my script to it, __Thank you very much!__

Comment: even tho you already gave me a solution can you/do you know why would ffmpeg close w/o arguments even tho the CMD counterpart doesn't close it? why is that bat file so different from the CMD when they both have the same command?

Comment: Just saw your edit, start /w ffmpeg.exe doesn't work it closes like ffmpeg alone does.

Comment: here is how it works. When you run cmd, you have an open window. it is in Keep mode in other words. when you run a batch file, it will auto close once the command completed. so by using cmd /k you mimic a cmd.exe window, so it will keep the window open. try this for arguments sake. create a batch and put `notepad.exe` save it and run. you will see notepad open, but your batch file will wait. once you close notepad, it will also exit the batch. This is because by default batch file will wait for it to complete. now try the same but do `cmd /k notepad.exe` then run and close notepad.

Comment: You will then see it will keep the cmd open, even though your notepad is closed. Same with ffmpeg, the command completed and will exit the batch once done, but cmd /k will keep the batch open.

Comment: so the purpose of the batch is to run in quite mode, without intervention, it's target is to run batch jobs, wait for them to complete and then exit, unless you tell it to wait. Also, if you feel I assisted you in solving your question, please do mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Thank you very much it helped me with exactly what i needed and your explanation is also great thanks again!